# Turn on darlington(s) with 3V MCU

Tags: microcontroller, driver

My goal is to get a 3.3V MCU (probably a ESP32) to drive this circuit. It is driven with a square wave from 15 to 40 Hz where the pulse width itself of 2.5 to 13 msec. When searching for answers, the solutions would assume a 3.3V to 5V level shifting and have the load above the transistors that get turned on.

The originally supplied PCB with microcontroller for this function has perished; *possibly related to the 12V input being 19.9 VDC?* Reviewing the circuits on the original MCU PCB wasn't straightforward as I believe it had been employed across various uses and functioned by coincidence more than by design.

**Diagram of what I'm trying to do:**

[image: Goal of the question: Drive this circuit with GPIO from MCU]

Pics of the PCB are on [imgur "post" or gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4la.jpg) and here is the [TIP142 Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00000914-1795651.pdf). Please note a couple conditions: The MCU voltage is supplied from the PCB, so will have 20VDC, which I will use a buck converter to 3.3V for the ESP32. The load is on the emitters and there is shared ground between the MCU and the PCB.

[image: Test setup with external resistors]

Testing Steps Performed

1. +20 V to input turns on the driver circuit, Input open or on ground and circuit is off.
2. Voltage divider set up with variable resistors; discovered base-ground resistor needed to be maxed; so it stayed fixed at 437Ω.
3. Vary the base voltage up and I noticed between 5 and 6 V, the circuit turns on.
4. Data point: With the divider connected and the circuit on and 6.3V measured on the input, the Top resistor was 789Ω. *Calculates to 15 mA of current.*
5. The lowest voltage I could observe the circuit turning on was 5.0 V.
6. Without changing the resistances, I disconnected the voltage divider from the input and measured 5.66 VDC between the resistors.

Comment: link to an injector spec.  Is the spec 5V = +/-10%?  Got any better transistors or FETs rated > 10A

Comment: You mean, like, to bypass all the crap on the board and roll my own stuff? (trying to resist the urge)